# Insert Multi Row Data into Multi Column Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Text file containing sets of three data items delimited by `;` to be inserted in three columns of mysql database table is being inserted in a single column. Found a snippet of code on SO and modified it according to requirement, but still doesn't work as required. Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks!

num.txt

```
one
two
three;
four
five
six;  
...
```

test.php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

$filename = "num.txt";
$handle   = fopen($filename, 'r');
$data     = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$rowsArr  = explodeRows($data);

function explodeRows($data) {
    $rowsArr = explode(";", $data);
    return $rowsArr;
    }

for($i=0;$i<count($rowsArr);$i++) {
    $cols = explodeRows($rowsArr[$i]);
    mysql_select_db("test", $db);
    $query = sprintf('INSERT INTO voter (fname, lname, add) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s")', $cols[0], $cols[1], $cols[2]);

    if (!mysql_query($query,$db))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";
    }
fclose($handle);
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

output with above :

```
fname | lname |  add

one   |       |
two   |       |
three |       |
---------------------
four  |       |
five  |       |
six   |       |
---------------------
...
```

error with above code

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 20
1 record added
```

output required

```
fname |lname  |add

one   | two   |three
---------------------
four  | five  |six
---------------------
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple MySQL workaround -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt' INTO TABLE table1
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  LINES TERMINATED BY ';\r\n'
  (column1, column2, @var)
  SET column3 = TRIM(TRAILING ';' FROM @var)
```

Just specify your table/column/file names.

[LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Getting this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'DATA' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line xx` Any clue?

Comment: This code works perfectly in MySQL command line console. Try to find the problem in php code that executes this statement.

Comment: I commented out all my codes from `$filename` till `fclose` then placed the `mysql_select_db("test", $db);` after the db connection codes and then inserted your codes with my file name, table & column names. Your codes seem very good. But, don't know how to use it :-( Please, help.

Comment: Getting this error after running code in MySql console `#29 - File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\test\num.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)`

Comment: Change all '\' to '/' in a file path.

Comment: I hadn't specified any file path. Just changed your `test.txt` to `num.txt` . No slashes.

Comment: So, MySQL says that file num.txt does not exist in D:\xampp\mysql\data\test directory. You need to set exact file path to your file, or copy file to default directory - D:\xampp\mysql\data\test and try again.

Comment: Got it correctly through the Sql console after specifying full path with forward slashes :-) But, getting same error while using php file. :-(

Comment: Maybe, you need to escape ('), e.g. LOAD DATA INFILE \'d:/test.txt\'... Also, try to find the answer or examples in the internet.

Comment: Was just going to do that. Please wait. I will try that and return.

Comment: Got it by specifying full path within single quotes with forward slashes :-) Thanks! Also for those who may have the same problem and get confused with the drive letter anywhere mentioned as C:\,  want to let you know that xampp is installed on drive D:\ C: was a typo when typing over here.